# styling <mat-select> inside a parent element

Tags: css, angular-material, angular6

```
<div>
<custom-mult-select>
<mat-select></mat-select>
</custom-multi-select>
</div>
```

I am not able to style the  width. I have tried the following way.

```
div.custom-multi-select.mat-select{
width: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it inside the mat-form-field then set your width..

```
<mat-form-field style="width:300px">
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option></mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your CSS and overwrite the current style by adding !important

```
custom-mult-select {
width: 175px!important;
}
```